# Using " GtkWidget *window " vs " GObject *window " in C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gobject

What is the correct syntax when using GTK+ 3 (and glade) for creating a simple window from an xml glade file? I have seen two methods that seem to do the same thing however the syntax is slightly different.

Example 1:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GObject *window;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.glade", NULL);

  window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void 
on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder; 
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));

    gtk_widget_show (window);                
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both should work, but I think it is more reasonable to use `GtkWidget` as you will need this type a lot more, so you do not need to write `GTK_WIDGET(obj)` all the time. You just need to 'convert' it once.

Please note that the official guide uses `GObject` type. ([here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html))

But after all you can decide, as you can easily 'convert' it to the type you need...

Comment: Did you mean it's better to use GObject instead of GtkWidget (because when you use a widget you have to convert back to object type, atleast based on the code above) when you go down to the line that starts with: window =

Comment: I personaly think that GtkWidget is a better choice as you will most likely use a widget type in gtk applications and not an object type... Imagine the fist example with a gtk_widget_show() or a gym_widget_destroy(), than you need a widget